# How to write python commands for gedit?

Tags: python, text-editor, shortcut, gedit

I come from an quite unsuccessful experience with MacVim. Vim is great but I am quite lazy and I don't have time to learn Vim scripting.

So I switched to gedit where I hope to use python directly (that is my favorite language). 
I would love to know how to do these 4 basic things:

1. Write a python script that is activated by a shortcut.
2. Take the selected text (or all the file) as the input of a python script
3. Print the output in place of the input (or after or in a new line)
4. Make the command available (clickable) in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the gedit API using

```
from gi.repository import GObject, Gedit
```

The python file created should be present along with .plugin file. This can be then loaded by Gedit.

There are  [extension interfaces](https://developer.gnome.org/gedit/stable/GeditWindowActivatable.html) which have to be used depending on the plugin.

This is a good [tutorial](http://www.micahcarrick.com/writing-plugins-for-gedit-3-in-python.html) I found on google.